# understand split behavior in apache camel

Tags: java, routes, split, apache-camel, integration-patterns

```
from("direct:A")
    .split(//expression that split msg into two msg M1,M2)
          .process(// here processing)
```

`.from("direct:A")` behaves like a java method i.e the thread that calls it will continue to `split`.

So what will happen in above case ?

Ley say Thread `t1` calls `from("direct:A")` then

It enters into `.split()` here the msg is divided into two new messages `M1` and `M2`.

Now from here on-wards will `t1` call `process()` for `M1` and `M2` synchronously ?

or

`process()` will be called for `M1` and `M2` in two new thread asynchronously ?

Comment: they are called sequentially. as good as a for loop. the body/message changes in each iteration. you can use the .log() method to figure out whats happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `process()` method is called sequentially. But you can activate parallel processing by adding an option.

From the [Camel doc](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html):

> parallelProcessing (default false): If enabled then processing the sub-messages
> occurs concurrently. Note the caller thread will still wait until all
> sub-messages has been fully processed, before it continues.

NB: If you are interested in splitter's performance, you can look for the streaming option.